# What is a good software package for technical drawings with shading?

Tags: vector, software-recommendation, drawing

I am a web developer so I am a coder normally not a designer. I have Illustrator on my PC and I have a lot of technical drawings to do for fencing that my client sells such as this one

[image]

Now this is a bit rough and ready but I am wondering am I using the best software for the task at hand or can you recommend any technical drawing software? I am looking for something that can add shading so it looks more realistic.

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: Hi Barry, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I dont think this question is on topic

Comment: This is an easy task for Illustrator, however if you are looking for something to *automatically* add lighting aspects, you'll *have* to look at 3D software.

Comment: Can ub recommend any 3d software

Comment: @joojaa I am unsure about that, why would we have a [tag:software-recommendation] tag when a software recommendation question would be off-topic?

Comment: It's like asking 'what is your favorite pen'? There's no right answer to this. There are dozens and dozens of illustration and 3D tools that can do this, but which to use is really going to come down to personal preference.

Comment: we have a lot of tags that are mostly out of topic. 3D is out of topic mostly. Anyway what is your budget. What is your client using?

Comment: You used the [tag:vector] tag, are you expecting the output to be vector?

Answer (score 1):

Autodesk Inventor and similar 3D CAD tools would make quick work of this sort of thing: http://www.autodesk.com/products/inventor/overview

Inventor is free for startups making less than $100,000 / yr. http://www.theguardian.com/sustainable-business/autodesk-sustainable-design-software-cost

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.sketchup.com/

Very easy 3d drawing program, easy to understand and use. If all you need is tehnical 3d, this can be very good for you.